# ffmpeg program written in C, cannot open my camera in macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavdevice/avdevice.h"

AVFormatContext* openCamera(void) {
    avdevice_register_all();
    AVFormatContext *ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVInputFormat *ifmt = av_find_input_format("avfoundation");
    if (ifmt != NULL) {
        AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
        av_dict_set(&opts, "video_size", "1280x720", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "framerate", "30", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "pixel_format", "uyvy422", 0);
        
        int ret = avformat_open_input(&ctx, "0", ifmt, &opts);
        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("no");
            avformat_free_context(ctx);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return ctx;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    openCamera();
}
```

My code run on Xcode. After I have added the plist file, the running program camera opens for about half a second and then closes. and console output

```
2022-02-22 00:39:19.372178+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x10640cf60> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2022-02-22 00:39:19.434783+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
2022-02-22 00:39:19.435262+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
2022-02-22 00:39:19.501780+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x10640f860> 30010C1C-93BF-11D8-8B5B-000A95AF9C6A
2022-02-22 00:39:19.605797+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-02-22 00:39:21.701071+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [] CMIOHardware.cpp:917:CMIODeviceStopStream the System is exiting
2022-02-22 00:39:21.701268+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [] CMIOHardware.cpp:1332:CMIOStreamCopyBufferQueue the System is exiting
2022-02-22 00:39:21.701538+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [] CMIOHardware.cpp:333:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData the System is exiting
2022-02-22 00:39:21.701767+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [] CMIO_DALA_System.cpp:264:GetPropertyData error 1970171760 (unop) getting property selector (inot) scope (glob) element 0
2022-02-22 00:39:21.702472+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [] CMIOHardware.cpp:333:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData the System is exiting
2022-02-22 00:39:21.702662+0800 ffmpeg-tool[5977:195724] [] CMIO_DALA_System.cpp:264:GetPropertyData error 1970171760 (unop) getting property selector (inot) scope (glob) element 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it just looks like all it does is open the camera and then return to main where it would exit and close the connection when the program is done.  You probably want to start reading packets in a loop if you want to keep the connection open and read from the camera.